# How to set id attribute for Bokeh widgets or layouts

Tags: python, bokeh

As I understood, Bokeh columns and rows are translating to div elements in html.
I was wondering if there is a way to assign id to a bokeh column/row just like what we do in html.

```
<div id="myid"></div>
```

ps. I have tried "name" attribute for a Div in bokeh, but it seems that it is not translated to "id" in html.

```
Div(name="myid")
```

Comment: Did you try `Div(id="myid")`? This throws no error and the value for `id` is set.

Comment: @mosc9575 It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh manages the DOM id's of its own components, this is necessary in order to acheive the Python <--> JS synchronization (currently DOM id's match Bokeh `Model` id's). While there is technically nothing to stop you from setting and overriding the auto-generated `id` property on Bokeh objects, and while this may "work" in some situations, please explicitly note that this usage is:

- not intended
- not supported

And may stop "working" at any time in the future, if it does happen to function now. Certainly, know that anything that causes an id to be non-uniqued or re-used across a session in a Bokeh server app will probably just blow up.

A much better approach would be to embed Bokeh objects into your own template using one of the [embedding APIs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) and then you can control everything about the DOM elements in your template (e.g. includng the ones you embed Bokeh objects inside).